# How to upload a file in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, file, webserver

I am having an issue while uploading a file, my code is here:

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['DOB']) && isset($_POST['address']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    # code...
$n=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$e=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$dob=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['DOB']));
$a=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['address']));
$p=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$t=time();
$d_of_reg=date('D M Y @ H.i.s', $t);

$cv=$_FILES['file']['name'];



// connect to the db here

mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Please we could not connect.. Try-again!!!');
mysql_select_db('joblessmen')or die('Please we could not connect to our database... Try-again!!!');

$sql="INSERT INTO `users`(`name`, `email`, `DOB`, `address`, `phone number`, `id`, `date_of_reg`) VALUES ('$n','$e','$dob','$a','$p','','$d_of_reg')";

if($sql_run=mysql_query($sql))
{
    echo "Thank you for registering. Joblessmen";
}



}
```

So I want to get the files to the server and it's telling me nothing when I `echo $_FILE['file']['name']` Please what I have to do? My wamp settings in php_fileinfo are on, any help would be appreciated.

please this is the other part for uploading the file which is not working i want it to upload a jpg and doc,docx,pdf file only this is my php code

```
if ( isset($_FILES['file']['name']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['DOB']) && isset($_POST['address']) && isset($_POST['phone'])) {
        # code...
    $n=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
    $e=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
    $dob=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['DOB']));
    $a=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['address']));
    $p=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
    $t=time();
    $d_of_reg=date('D M Y @ H.i.s', $t);


    //$cv=$_FILES['file']['name'];

/*
    function upload_cv_check()
    {
        // Define some variables
        $max_size = 200000;
        $files_directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/seabird/top-menu/cv';
        $file_name = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
        $file_size = filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        $file_extension = strrchr($_FILES['file']['name'], '.'); 

        // Available extensions
        $extensions = array('.doc', '.pdf','.docx');

        // Return false if extension is not allowed
        if(!in_array($file_extension, $extensions))
            return false;

        // Return false if file size is over limit
        if($file_size > $max_size)
            return false;
            echo "file must be 2mb";

        // Fast way to rewrite file name, do your own
        $final_file_name = strtr($file_name, 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ', 'AAAAAACEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiioooooouuuuyy');
        $final_file_name = preg_replace('/([^.a-z0-9]+)/i', '-', $final_file_name);

        // Move the file to your server
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['my_image']['tmp_name'], $files_directory.$final_file_name);

        // Here is the link to your file, adapt it
        $file = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/my_files_directory/'.$final_file_name;
    }
*/

    /*
    $extension=strtolower(substr($cv, strpos($cv, '.') + 1));
    $type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
    $size=$_FILES['file']['size'];
    $tmp_name=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $max_size = 300000;

    if (isset($cv)) {

        if (!empty($cv)) {
            if (($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'jpeg' ) && $type=='image/jpeg' && $type=='image/jpg'  && $size<=$max_size) {
                $location='cv/';

                if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location)) {
                    echo "file has been uploaded";
                }
            }else {echo "there was an error";}
        }else{echo "file must be a image format.";}
        # code...
    }else{echo "please choose a file now";}
    */


    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location);
    $tmp_name=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $location='cv/';


    // connect to the db here

    mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Please we could not connect.. Try-again!!!');
    mysql_select_db('joblessmen')or die('Please we could not connect to our database... Try-again!!!');

    $sql="INSERT INTO `users`(`name`, `email`, `DOB`, `address`, `phone number`, `id`, `date_of_reg`) VALUES ('$n','$e','$dob','$a','$p','','$d_of_reg')";

    if($sql_run=mysql_query($sql))
    {
        echo "Thank you for registering. Joblessmen";
        //echo $cv=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    }



    }
```

so i want it to upload a file from either of the extensions but it not working it is tell undefined index please what can i do

Comment: Does your <form> tag include the enctype="multipart/form-data" parameter?

Comment: You need to show the form.

Comment: Need to show the complete code, staring from form HTML and to you end PHP code... Do print_r($_FILE) to get the complete file info irrespective of file the object that you use. If you have an empty array, probably there is a bug in you form, that prevents file from being posted. Added Multipart form data in the enctype? is the form method post? do you have an action file set?

Comment: Did you tried `$_FILES['file']['name']` its not `$_FILE` Its `$_FILES` Manual: `http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php`

Comment: you can check here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Create a [Codepad] (http://www.codepad.org), You form should have include the enctyp="multipart/form-date" . This link may help you.  http://php.sysaxiom.com/file_uploading_system.php

Comment: @ frank1fr i have added but enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form but it is not echoing the $_FILES['file']['name'] what should i do and i want to use the format doc and pdf and nothing apart from that how do i do that???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Make sure you have mentioned `enctype="multipart/form-data"` parameter

2) You can access the file by

```
$file=$_FILES['file']['name'];
```

`$_FILES['name']['tmp_name']` will give you the temporary path of the file.

Then you can use the below function to move the file from temporary path to your file system.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['name']['tmp_name'],"Your filesystem path");
```

Answer (score 1):

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ,"upload/".$_FILES['file']['name']); 
 $file= $_FILES['file']['name'];

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code with multiple tests to do what you want :

```
// Define some variables
$max_size = 200000;
$files_directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/my_files_directory/';
$file_name = basename($_FILES['my_image']['name']);
$file_size = filesize($_FILES['my_image']['tmp_name']);
$file_extension = strrchr($_FILES['my_image']['name'], '.'); 

// Available extensions
$extensions = array('.png', '.gif', '.jpg');

// Return false if extension is not allowed
if(!in_array($file_extension, $extensions))
    return false;

// Return false if file size is over limit
if($file_size > $max_size)
    return false;

// Fast way to rewrite file name, do your own
$final_file_name = strtr($file_name, 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ', 'AAAAAACEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiioooooouuuuyy');
$final_file_name = preg_replace('/([^.a-z0-9]+)/i', '-', $final_file_name);

// Move the file to your server
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['my_image']['tmp_name'], $files_directory.$final_file_name);

// Here is the link to your file, adapt it
$file = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/my_files_directory/'.$final_file_name;
```

Moreover, you need to have this line when opening your form :

```
<form method="your_method" action="your_action" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: please @Pauloscorps how do i do that for a extensions pdf and doc only please how do i do that... before going to the server folder. please